# animated Gradient wont be shown on Smartphone

Tags: css, css-animations, responsive, gradient

my animated css gradient work perfect on Mac but not on my smartphone.

Somebody knows why?

```
selector {
display: inline-block;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgb(175, 46, 201), rgb(175, 46, 201), rgb(64, 207, 207), rgb(64, 207, 207));
background-size: 300%;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: 900;
font-size: 5vw;
letter-spacing: -5px;
text-transform: uppercase;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
animation: animated_text 5s ease-in-out infinite;
-moz-animation: animated_text 5s ease-in-out infinite;
-webkit-animation: animated_text 5s ease-in-out infinite;
```

}

```
@keyframes animated_text {
0% { background-position: 0px 50%; }
50% { background-position: 100% 50%; }
100% { background-position: 0px 50%; }
```

}

Comment: did you check verion of your browser?? in your smartphone

Comment: it isn’t working on any of my mobile browsers, not on safari, not on Chrome etc

Comment: remove webkit from the gradient

Comment: doesn’t work out

Answer (score 0):

As well as the -webkit- versions of the several properties you have, also use the non-prefixed versions.

This snippet works fine for me on IOS 15 Safari:

```css
.selector {
  display: inline-block;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgb(175, 46, 201), rgb(175, 46, 201), rgb(64, 207, 207), rgb(64, 207, 207));
  background-size: 300%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 5vw;
  letter-spacing: -5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  text-fill-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  animation: animated_text 5s ease-in-out infinite;
  -moz-animation: animated_text 5s ease-in-out infinite;
  -webkit-animation: animated_text 5s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: animated_text 5s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes animated_text {
  0% {
    background-position: 0px 50%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0px 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="selector">ABCD</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but this does not work on mobile...

Comment: Which mobile are you using as it seems ok on iOS.

Comment: iphone 12 pro max with the newest version. On my Ipad Pro it is also not working

Comment: I've just run this snippet on an iPad and an iPhoneSE and they both show the animated gradient OK so sorry I don't think I can help further as I can't reproduce the problem once there is a version without the webkit prefixes as well as with them.